# is 7zip faster archiving (solid or not solid)?

Tags: 7zip

I am creating a .7z file, with the -ms=on flag, which is supposed to result in a solid archive. But the listing of the archive, shows that solid is off.

But my really question is what is the fastest way to archive with 7zip, solid or not solid.

I really don't care about compression. What I want is the fastest elapsed time - for creating the archive and especially for the unpack of the archive. And I heard that solid .7z is very fast for the unpack. I am using Powershell to do the commands. (the resulting archive is about 760MB and about 176K files). It is taking me about 12 minutes to create and 8 minutes to unpack.

```
[string]$zipper = "$($Env:ProgramFiles)\7-Zip\7z.exe"
[Array]$archive = "C:\zip\GL.7z"
[Array]$flags = "a","-t7z","-mx0","-mmt=on","-ms=on", "-r"
[Array]$skip = "-xr!.svn","-xr!.vs","-xr!bin","-xr!obj","-xr!Properties","-x!*.csproj","-x!*.user","-x!*.sln","-x!*.suo","-x!web.config","-x!web.*.config"
$ElapsedTime = [System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch]::StartNew()
echo "Toby..."
[Array]$in = "C:\wwwroot\Toby"
[Array]$cmd = $flags + $archive + $in + $skip
& $zipper $cmd
```

Comment: My guess is that -mx=0 (no compression) is incompatible with solid mode. Try -mx=1 with solid and see if it works with that option.

Comment: Also, I think you are mistaken about the speed. It is my understanding that solid archives take longer to pack and unpack.

Comment: I changed it to -mx=1 and yes, it does now create a solid archive. I also suspected that. I did read that solid was faster in performance, and I will post the results of solid/non-solid when the archive is done. See: http://www.intowindows.com/how-to-make-7-zip-faster/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

plushpuffin was correct, solid archives are only created if you have compression on e.g. (-mx1).

Here is the timing of what it took to do compress and uncompress
The original is 950MB of disk space in 176K files, mostly JPG.

```
7z uncompressed, not-solid,-mx0
    size: 728 MB
    pack: 12:28
    unpack: 9:28

7z compressed, solid -mx1
    size: 555 MB 
    pack: 18:18
    unpack: 9:13

7z compressed, solid -mx1 -mmt=off (single thread)
    size: 555 MB 
    pack: 22:48
    unpack: 10:32
```

Comment: If you truly value speed over space, you should test with other compression options. Try other formats such as LZMA2, and try with -mmt=off. Using multiple threads may actually be lowering your throughout. See http://superuser.com/a/550077

Comment: I saw that post. The limiting factor in speed is I/0 it is not CPU bound. Thus it matters less what the compression rate is.  But having more than one thread. Actually helps, since 7zip seems to be written in a way that does more. Blocking on I/o, so this way one maximizes the I/o throughout.

Comment: Ok, never mind then. Sorry if I wasted any of your time with my suggestions, just trying to offer a different perspective.

Comment: No problem , I appreciate the input

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how you want to use the archive.  If you're wanting smallest archive possible and will want ALL the files in the archive at once (all or nothing), and you're okay with losing everything if any part of it is corrupted (or adding blocking and recovery code, making the file larger), then 7z would be fine.
If you want to look at one or several files (rather than decompressing the entire archive) or to add, change, or remove files, then you would want the.zip format because it can do that. It can decompress just the file name index so you can choose one or more files to extract.  .7z would have to decompress the entire archive every single time and then re-compress the entire archive, if that were needed (adding a file, for instance).
Also, if there is damage to a file in the archive, with .zip, the remaining files are likely still recoverable.  Unless 7z is compressed with blocking and recovery code added, then the entire archive of files would likely be lost.
For my use, I think that the .zip format offers more data safety than 7z and much better DE-compress speed for a file or two, or adding or deleting files.
The safety of my data and ease/speed of handling single file viewing, adding, etc. are my primary considerations.  So I prefer the non-solid zip format.
Plus ZIP is not a proprietary format.  You won't lose access to your archives if you later decide to switch to different archive software.
Just my two cents,
AnneF

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: 7z has a solid block size setting, one of the options is "non-solid"

Comment: Great answer.  Exactly the kind of information I was looking for Thanks !